Movie with a policeman on drugs
I don't remember a lot about the movie. 

The main actor is known.
The main character is a policeman on drugs. He's kind of crazy.
It's an American movie in English of course.
I remember a scene where he goes on a crime scene or something and he's high and starts hallucinating some animals? Not sure about that last detail.
I'd say it was released between 3 and 7 years ago.

That's all I remember. What movie is this?

Some movies with drug addicted Cops: Bad Lieutenant, Léon: The Professional

Possibly also Bad Lieutenant: Port of Call New Orleans.

Are you sure it was a movie and not True Detective?

The movie I was looking for was Bad Lieutenant: Port of Call New Orleans. 

The main character is played by the known actor Nicolas Cage. 
The scene I was talking about is the one with the iguana. Here are some images of the scene.


You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the descriptions from the question to flesh out the answer a little more.

Is it better now ?

Meh, I guess it is.

Possibly Filth(2013) starring James McAvoy
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1450321/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_6

You might want to elaborate in which way this movie fits to the descriptions from the question to flesh out the answer a little more.
